# Android SQlite application crashes when I try to run it

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have attempted to create a viewable SQLite database to view but it keeps crashing when I try to open it.
I have tried opening it multiple times and changed a few things to try and fix it, but seeing as I have not fixed it I probably made it worse.
I can't get anywhere when I open it and it crashes straight away. Sorry for the wall of code but I thought I may aswell give you too much info rather than too little.
Any input is appreciated.

### DBHelper.java

```
package com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public SQLiteDatabase DB;
    public String DBPath;
    public static String DBName = "sample";
    public static final int version = '1';
    public static Context currentContext;
    public static String tableName = "Resource";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, version);
        currentContext = context;
        DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
        createDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void createDatabase() {
        boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

        if (dbExists) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
            DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    tableName +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('M','shumi','India',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('C','sarah','India',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('D','Lavya','USA',20);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('V','Avi','EU',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('T','Shenoi','Bangla',25);");
            DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    tableName +
                    " Values ('L','Lamha','Australia',20);");
        }


    }

    private boolean checkDbExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

### ListViewFromSQLiteDB.java

```
package com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class ListViewFromSQLiteDB extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

       <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
           android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.DataListView"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

### Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

### LogCat:

```
    05-16 23:31:02.535: D/AndroidRuntime(31302): Shutting down VM
05-16 23:31:02.555: W/dalvikvm(31302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4143f2a0)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb/com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb.ListViewFromSQLiteDB}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.onCreate(ListViewFromSQLiteDB.java:18)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-16 23:31:02.585: E/AndroidRuntime(31302):    ... 11 more
05-16 23:31:42.800: D/AndroidRuntime(32421): Shutting down VM
05-16 23:31:42.800: W/dalvikvm(32421): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4143f2a0)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb/com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb.ListViewFromSQLiteDB}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.onCreate(ListViewFromSQLiteDB.java:18)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-16 23:31:42.810: E/AndroidRuntime(32421):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ListViewFromSQLiteDB.DataListView
```

You declared a class in `AndroidManifest.xml` that does not seem to exist. Maybe what you mean was:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.listviewfromsqlitedb.ListViewFromSQLiteDB"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Also note that each activity that you intend to launch have to be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If that is your full xml you will have to declare also `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks, I should not have included MainActivity. I got mixed up and included the wrong thing! Cheers ill test it out and get back to you.

Comment: Tis still crashing after trying a few things. I'm gonna go back and recheck over a few things in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to the manifest. Thanks for your help guys.